# Writing the Absolute and Relative Average in an Application Form

Tags: masters, application, gpa

In the application form of a master's degree program I'm applying for, I've stumbled upon this:

**Please indicate both the absolute and the relative average of your previous degree.**

What does this mean? I'm not quite sure, but I don't think my transcript of records indicates a relative average, so what should I do?

Comment: When I applied, I sometimes had to give my overall GPA and then the GPA in my actual major (so excluding things like English lit, etc.). Maybe that's what they mean by a "relative" GPA? I'm not sure though.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not really sure, because for example, this link says something completely different: https://joblessenggstud.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/absolute-grading-or-relative-grading/

Comment: That link talks about how individual professors assign grades. I can't imagine that's what they mean on an application, since it's almost impossible to figure out. You should probably just ask the admissions office what they want.

Comment: Problem solved: They were basically asking me to write the exact GPA as mentioned on the transcript of records (for example: 4.8 out of 5) and then also calculate the percentage of it: 4.8 out of 5 = 96%

Comment: Vote to close as OP said "Problem solved".

Comment: I'd rather recommend that the OP self-answer, for the benefit of future generations. @Bewildered: could you please answer your question, by copying your comment into the answer box?

Comment: @StephanKolassa OP hasn't been seen for three months... I will quote the OP in the answer box and delete if they return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.P. says in comments that they solved their own problem:

> Problem solved: They were basically asking me to write the exact GPA as mentioned on the transcript of records (for example: 4.8 out of 5) and then also calculate the percentage of it: 4.8 out of 5 = 96% –